Filter out dependency telemetry with applicationinsights javaagent 3.5.4
I have an EAP7 application running in OpenShift with a javaagent attached with application insights (Azure). I have followed the guide for filtering telemetry and configuring the agent with the guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-sampling-overrides
My applicationinsights.json file looks like this:
    {
        "sampling": {
           "percentage": 100,
            "overrides": [
                {
                    "telemetryType": "request",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "key": "http.url",
                            "value": "https?://[^/]+/health.*",
                            "matchType": "regexp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "percentage": 0
                },
                {
                    "telemetryType": "request",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "key": "http.url",
                            "value": "https?://[^/]+/metrics.*",
                            "matchType": "regexp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "percentage": 0
                },
                {
                    "telemetryType": "request",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "key": "http.request.method",
                            "value": "HEAD",
                            "matchType": "strict"
                        }
                    ],
                    "percentage": 0
                },
                {
                    "telemetryType": "trace",
                    "percentage": 0
                },
                
            ]
        },
        "instrumentation": {
            "jdbc": {
                "masking": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        }
    }

Which works for the metrics and health endpoints.
However i am facing an issue with a certain dependency:

I have tried with numerous of filters like:
{
    "notWorkingFilters": [
        {
            "telemetryType": "dependency",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "message",
                    "value": "GET \/",
                    "matchType": "strict"
                }
            ],
            "percentage": 0
        },
        {
            "telemetryType": "dependency",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "message",
                    "value": ".*localhost:5778.*",
                    "matchType": "regexp"
                }
            ],
            "percentage": 0
        },
        {
            "telemetryType": "dependency",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "name",
                    "value": "GET \/",
                    "matchType": "strict"
                }
            ],
            "percentage": 0
        },
        {
            "telemetryType": "dependency",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "name",
                    "value": ".*localhost:5778.*",
                    "matchType": "regexp"
                }
            ],
            "percentage": 0
        },
        {
            "telemetryType": "dependency",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "http.url",
                    "value": "http://localhost:5778.*",
                    "matchType": "regexp"
                }
            ],
            "percentage": 0
        },
        {
            "telemetryType": "dependency",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "http.url",
                    "value": ".*5778.*",
                    "matchType": "regexp"
                }
            ],
            "percentage": 0
        }
    ]
}

IT is just for formatting reasons i have added the "notWorkingFilters" :-)
None of them filters out this dependency. Any idea what i am missing and what i can do in order to remove this?
I have also tried with adding them as telemetryType "request" and specified it on HTTP level, without luck.

Are you still facing the issue. @lhn_dk

Yes. I haven't found a solution yet.

Checking on the same. @lhn_dk

Thanks for your effort. I will look into it and see if it solves my problem.

Yes please. @lhn_dk

The approach and dependencies you are following is accurately given when you want to filter out dependency telemetry with application insights. Check below ways to try fixing the issue.
According to the MSDoc,

When the call is made to an external service, you need to know the identity of that server so you can set the dependency.target field appropriately.

As mentioned above, try providing the target key type under telemetry dependencies shown in the below way.
applicationinsights.json
Filtertarget
{
    "telemetryType": "dependency",
         "attributes": [
             {
                 "key": "target",
                 "value": ".*localhost:5778.*",
                 "matchType": "regexp"
             }
         ],
            "percentage": 0
}

Also, here the dependencies could be logged as HTTP, SQL, or other types, and it may differs based on the external call it is making. If the dependency is HTTP related, try filtering it by type attribute. These are all few ways you can try to resolve the conflict as there is no exact issue found with the insights Json.
Note: Also check the cache issue whether it is appropriately loaded by the agent.

Thanks for the response, and sorry for the delay in me getting back. I have now tried your suggestion, but i still get the item in my application insights. I have tried other changes that works to confirm that this is not a caching issue.
